# Funcion Card Game con Queues en Javascript

Tags: javascript, queue

Estoy queriendo resolver esta función y no logro dar con la respuesta correcta; les dejo la consigna, la solución propuesta (que no es correcta y no logro aun encontrar el error) y los tests.
Gracias desde ya!

**Implementar la función cardGame: a partir de dos Queue que va a recibir como parámetros tiene que determinar quién será el ganador del juego de cartas.** Las reglas de dicho juego son las siguientes:

- Cada jugador tendrá un mazo con cartas numeradas del 1 al 12
- Estos mazos estarán implementados a partir de la estructura de Queue
- En cada turno del juego, cada jugador lanzará la carta que se encuentre primero en su mazo (Queue)
- El jugador que tenga el número más alto en el turno ganará dicho turno
- El jugador que gane dicho turno se quedará con ambas cartas agregándolas al final del mazo (Primero la suya y luego la de su contrincante)
- En el caso de que haya empate ambos pierden las cartas y no se agregan a ningún mazo
- El ganador del juego será quien deje a su oponente sin cartas en su mazo
  Aclaración: la función cardGame debe retornar "A wins!" en el caso de que el ganador sea el jugador A o "B wins!" en caso contrario. Puede ocurrir que haya empate, en dicho caso retornat "Game tie!"

Ejemplo:

- mazoUserA = [4,2,10,11]
- mazoUserB = [6,9,10,3]

Primer mano:
A --> 4  vs  6 <-- B [6 > 4 entonces gana la mano B y pone ambas cartas en su mazo, colocando primero la a]

- mazoUserA = [2,10,11]
- mazoUserB = [6,9,10,3,6,4]

**Este es el código que pude armar:**

```js
var cardGame = function(mazoUserA, mazoUserB) {
  if (mazoUserA.size === 0 || mazoUserB.size === 0) return null;
  if (mazoUserA.size !== mazoUserB.size) return null;
  for (i = 0; i < mazoUserA.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; i < mazoUserB.length; i++) {
      if (mazoUserA[i] > mazoUserB[j]) {
        mazoUserA.push(mazoUserA[i], mazoUserB[j]);
      } else {
        mazoUserB.push(mazoUserB[j], mazoUserA[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  if (mazoUserA.length === mazoUserB.length) {
    return "Game tie!";
  } else if (mazoUserB.length === 0) {
    return "A wins!";
  } else if (mazoUserA.length === 0) {
    return "B wins!";
  }
};
```

**Y estos son los tests para chequear la solución**

```js
describe('EJERCICIO 6: cardGame', function() {
  var mazoUserA;
  var mazoUserB;
  beforeEach(function() {
    mazoUserA = new Queue();
    mazoUserB = new Queue();
  });
  it('Debe devoler `Game tie!` si el juego termino empatado', function() {
    mazoUserA.enqueue(4);
    mazoUserA.enqueue(7);
    mazoUserA.enqueue(11);
    mazoUserB.enqueue(4);
    mazoUserB.enqueue(7);
    mazoUserB.enqueue(11);
    expect(cardGame(mazoUserA, mazoUserB)).to.equal("Game tie!");
  });
  it('Debe devoler `A wins!` si el jugador A es el ganador', function() {
    mazoUserA.enqueue(4);
    mazoUserA.enqueue(2);
    mazoUserA.enqueue(10);
    mazoUserA.enqueue(11);
    mazoUserB.enqueue(6);
    mazoUserB.enqueue(9);
    mazoUserB.enqueue(10);
    mazoUserB.enqueue(3);
    expect(cardGame(mazoUserA, mazoUserB)).to.equal("A wins!");
  });
  it('Debe devoler `B wins!` si el jugador B es el ganador', function() {
    mazoUserB.enqueue(4);
    mazoUserB.enqueue(2);
    mazoUserB.enqueue(10);
    mazoUserB.enqueue(11);
    mazoUserA.enqueue(6);
    mazoUserA.enqueue(9);
    mazoUserA.enqueue(10);
    mazoUserA.enqueue(3);
    expect(cardGame(mazoUserA, mazoUserB)).to.equal("B wins!");
  });
});
```

Comment: @Benito-B Entiendo que esa comprobacion solo se hace al inicio, para asegurarse que ambos jugadores tengan cartas y la cantidad de cartas sean iguales para ambos.

Comment: Efectivamente, @AgustinG.. Mi culpa, no leí bien el problema :)

Answer (score 0):

Reemplace tu funcion que analiza las cartas por un `do... while`, que lo que hace es ejecutar un bloque de codigo, y luego analiza una condicion. Si se cumple lo vuelve a ejecutar, sino sale.

- Guardo el valor de las cartas en las variables `cartaA` y `cartaB`, inmediatamente las elimino de los mazos de los jugadores
- Ahora solo comparo, si A gana la mano, coloco las dos cartas en su cola, de lo contrario las coloco en el mazo de B. Si hay empate, no hago nada ya que las habia eliminado inicialmente.

En el momento que uno de los competidores se quede sin cartas, la condicion `(mazoUserA.length > 0 && mazoUserB.length > 0)` arrojará false y obtendrás el resultado del juego.

> edit: agregué unos console.log para ir viendo el resultado del juego en cada mano.

```js
const cardGame = (mazoUserA, mazoUserB) => {

  if (mazoUserA.length === 0 || mazoUserB.length === 0) return null;
  if (mazoUserA.length !== mazoUserB.length) return null;
 
 do{
   const cartaA = mazoUserA[0];
   const cartaB = mazoUserB[0];
   mazoUserA.shift();
   mazoUserB.shift();
  
   if(cartaA > cartaB){
    mazoUserA.push(cartaA);
    mazoUserA.push(cartaB);
   } else if(cartaA < cartaB){
    mazoUserB.push(cartaB);
    mazoUserB.push(cartaA);
   }
   console.log("Resultado parcial")
   console.log("Jugador A: ", mazoUserA)
   console.log("Jugador B: ", mazoUserB)
  }while(mazoUserA.length > 0 && mazoUserB.length > 0)
 

  if (mazoUserA.length === mazoUserB.length) {
    return "Game tie!";
  } else if (mazoUserB.length === 0) {
    return "A wins!";
  } else if (mazoUserA.length === 0) {
    return "B wins!";
  }
  
};
let mazoUserA = [8,2,10,11]
let mazoUserB = [6,9,10,3]
console.log(cardGame(mazoUserA,mazoUserB))
```